# Moving average - MySQL

Tags: mysql, statistics, average, moving-average

I'm trying to implement system-wide login throttling and I need to calculate the daily average number of failed login attempts from the last 3 months.

I'm currently inserting a record on every login fail, each with a timestamp. How can I do this in MySQL?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(cnt)
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM mytable
         WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()
      GROUP BY DATE(`date`)) x
```

Assuming you have a table `mytable` with field `date` of type `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`